# Multiple script tags not working in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I'm building a website for a friend, I'm currently using jquery-1.4.3.min.js, corners.js, equalcols.js, and a pre-load image script in the head. Everything works great.

Problem is, I now need FancyBox (LightBox alternative) for a page and it won't seem to work! I know it's because something is conflicting with another but I have no idea what. Is it the order in the head? Or something else? Have tried LightBox and that doesn't work either.

It either doesn't work and stops the EqualCols.js from working, or everything else works EXCEPT the FancyBox for the mini-image gallery that is needed.

The head code is as below: (without FancyBox in there)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PRELOAD MENU IMAGES BEGINNING -->
    <script>
        var myimages=new Array()
        function preloadimages(){
        for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length ;
        i + myimages [ i ] =new Image ( myimages [ i ]
        src=preloadimages.arguments[i] } Enter path of images to be preloaded
        inside parenthesis. Extend list as desired. preloadimages ( images /
        home-h.png " images / about-h.png " images / services-rates-h.png "
        images / past-work-h.png " images / contact-h.png " images /
        shop-specials-h.png " images / free-quote-h.png " images /
        book-now-h.png ")
</script>
    <!-- PRELOAD MENU IMAGES END -->

    <!-- stop curvery corners error in IE -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/corners.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var curvyCornersVerbose = false;
    </script>
    <!-- stop curvery corners error in IE -->

    <!-- EQUAL COLS START -->
    <script src="js/equalcols.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#left-col,#right-col').equalCols();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- EQUAL COLS END -->

</head>
```

Is anyone able to tell me where I'd need to put the FancyBox coding for everything to work? Or what else I can do to get it to work? What are the rules? I've researched on Google and can't seem to find the answer I'm after.

The FancyBox code I need to implement is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Do I need the top line there if I'm using this already?:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Fancybox code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#single_image').fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Just tried that, still no luck - didn't work :(

Here is what I'm using (as per the FancyBox website) for the images, at the moment it's just a "test" image.

<a id="single_image" href="images/1_b.jpg"><img src="images/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

Comment: Not sure what the "single_image" is doing but that's what the How-To-Use page says to do on FancyBox website.

Comment: Where do I put that FancyBox code? I put it below the replacement I just made and above the PRELOAD MENU IMAGES script and it doesn't work, it also stops EqualCols from working now too. Any idea's? (Thanks for the help by the way!)

Comment: can you provide me a `LINK` where I can view this page or just create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't have a live version with the gallery/FancyBox I'm trying to do but I can quickly upload it for you, I'm new to stackoverflow is there a way I can message you the link? Thanks.

Comment: Ok here is the live version with the code changes you said to make (notice the EqualCols no longer works, right-border on the left-col doesn't match the right-col height).

http://www.icp.t15.org/test/past-work2.htm

Comment: change `<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>` and give it a go...

Comment: Tried that, EqualCols seems to work now, and when I click on the image it doesn't just link to the big image, it does nothing at all now.

Idea's? Have updated the live version for you to see. 

If you like you can email me, my email is on my profile :) THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

below code is working sample - the fancybox iframe version. 
make sure that you add anchor tag in your html/jsp

```
      <!--  The popup iframe . The href value will be updated dynamically -->
<a class="iframe" id="iframe" href="/YourApp/imagePopup.do"></a>
```

the include block is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
```

/**
jquery ready function
*/
$(document).ready(function(){

```
// popup for showing 
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
    'autoDimensions':false,
    'width'                 : 770,
    'height'                : 'auto', // height is controlled using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css line 79
    'centerOnScroll'  : true,
    'scrolling':'auto',
   // 'autoScale': true,
    'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
    'enableEscapeButton' :true,
    'hideOnContentClick': false, 
    'type':'iframe'
    ,'onStart' :function(){$.fancybox.showActivity();}

    ,'onClosed' :function(){ }
  });
```

}); // end ready

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not really wanting to use iframe.
Do you know why it's not letting me use it as it is?
A friend has told me it's because of the order of the js's in the head but I can't seem to figure out which order it should be in!